# Bouncing ball loses its forward momentum after the first bounce

Tags: unity, physics

I've created a bouncing ball in Unity, and I want to bounce the ball across the field, but the results I get seem very unrealistic.

The ball should bounce in the direction it was launched 2 or 3 more times, but after the first launch the next bounce is bouncing at the same place, going straight into the air. I also didn't see any spin effect on the ball. How can solve this problem?

[image: Ball bouncing]

And here's my physics settings

[image: Physic material]
[image: Rigidbody]

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem in a fresh project and was unable to. I added a sphere and a plane, added a script to the sphere which gives it an impuls on a keypress, and gave the sphere a rigidbody and a physics material set up exactly like in your screenshot. It behaved the way I would expect it to.

Comment: I'm confused. You mean you've tried and it unable to work(It still have the horizontal break problem?) or it's not.

Comment: I also try to tune the dynamic and static friction but it still have this effect. Another settings that i didn't provide you is I use the bounciness threshold = 0.7 becuase my fixed area is only 8X8 grid in unity so i need to scale the force and the threshold down to make it bounce and not to stop too early. I'm not sure that this is cause of the problem? but i think it's not.

Comment: Does the rotation of the ball matter?

Comment: Angular Drag is set to '3', this will stop the ball from rotating and therefor kill the forward momentum. Set that down to zero and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: @allnodcoms I have set it to zero but the ball is not stop from rolling. Also sometime if i set it too high the ball seems to spin backward once it hit the ground

Comment: OK, I take it the settings you posted are for the ball? What settings are there on the pitch? Does it have a Rigidbody? Physics Material?

Comment: @allnodcoms Yes the setting is for the ball. On pitch object has only box collider. Do i need to attach any physic material on the pitch? But i ithink if i add the rigidbody to my pitch it will fall down together. and i just try to freeze both position and rotation of the pitch it's not help.

Comment: You can apply a Physics material to the pitch (in the collider), and you don't need a Rigidbody on it, I just wondered if there was one. It looks like it should be a friction setting problem, but knowing the code that adds the impulse to the ball (or not) would sure help.

Comment: @allnodcoms I use the Impluse force mode on the ball. And I did try to add the physic material on pitch it not that help. In my opinion is to stop the ball rolling on the floor I need the angular drag to stop it but maybe there's this kind of problem instead.

Comment: Also this is not happens all the time. In some trajectory the bouncing looks realistic but some is not.

Comment: Normal drag will slow and stop the ball, you don't need angular drag for that. Friction between the ball and the pitch will also slow it. As your problem is intermittent, and dependant on trajectory it would seem logical that it's a settings problem rather than a code issue, so the only thing I can suggest there is to keep changing things up until you get the result you are after, I would check to make sure you are not accidentally adding some other force that stops the forward momentum though - just to be sure.

Comment: @allnodcoms Thank you very much for your suggestion. I think the orientation of the ball is matter since it's like a spinning effect then the ball friction direction can be apply in the wrong direction. (Like a shear force)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answer. I think i found a solution. The solution is reduce the FixedTimestep into 0.01 instead of 0.02(default). I think this will make the physic much more precise(Since every thing on pitch happen in 8x8 grid).